# Is this combinatorial optimization problem NP-hard?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, mathematical-optimization, np-complete

I working on a combinatorial optimization problem that I suspect is NP-hard, and a genetic algorithm has been working well with our dataset.  We're a research group and plan to publish our results in our field (not in math or CS), and I'd like to explore the NP-hard question before sending the manuscript out for review.

There are two main questions:

1) I'd like to know whether this particular optimization problem has been studied.  I've heavily searched the lit but haven't seen anything exactly the same.

2) If the problem hasn't been studied, I might take a crack at doing a reducibility proof, and would like some pointers to good NP-complete candidates for the reduction.

The problem can be described in two ways, as a subsequence variant, and as a bipartite graph problem.

In the subsequence flavor, I want to find a "relaxed" subsequence that allows permutations, and optimize to minimize the permutation count.  For example:  (. = any other char)

Query: abc, Target: ..b.a.b.c., Result: abc   (normal subsequence)

Query: abc, Target: ..b.a.c.a., Result: bac   (subsequence with one permutation)

The bipartite formulation is a matching problem or linear assignment problem, with the graph partitioned into query character nodes and target character nodes.  The edges connect the query characters to the target characters, such that there is exactly one edge from each query char to a target char.  The objective function is to minimize the number of edge crossings (also called "crossing number" in the lit).  This is similar to bipartite graph layout algorithms that reorder node placement to minimize edge crossings, but my problem requires the that both node orders stay fixed.

Any thoughts from the experts on questions 1 or 2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are not publishing in math or CS, a NP-completeness result will be irrelevant and just irritate the biologist or MD doing the review. Been there.

Comment: What is your meaning of permutation? One involving only two chars? Or only two adjacent ones? A permutation I think in its general meaning allows you to rearrange the whole string, but then the problem becomes trivial?

Comment: If I prove it NP-hard, do I get co-authorship?

Comment: Would, Query: abc Target: ..c.b.a.a Result: cba, be three permutations (as per your use of the term) then? If so, then maybe you mean transpositions rather than permutations. A transposition is the swapping of two adjacent characters. Also, out of curiousity, how many unique characters are there in the query/target?

Answer (score 2):

Just some idea: Does it somehow equivalent to finding the minimal number of swap needed to sort an array (MIN-SBR)? If yes, this is [NP-Hard](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.7886).

(btw, are you working on something [similar to this](http://grimm.ucsd.edu/GRIMM/)?)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is NP-hard. See work by Pevzner and Hannehali. A paper that comes to mind is titled ``From Cabbage to Turnip''. The idea is to find the minimum number of inversions to go from one string to another. They have a polytime algorithm for this.

Answer (score 0):

*The problem with "word problem" should be harder, right? – J-16 SDiZ 14*

Yes, having multiple occurrences of the char in the target seems to make my problem harder than MIN-SBR, so from that angle my problem would be at least as hard as NP-complete.  On the other hand, I'm not yet clear on how their central notion of block reversals would affect my claim of NP-completeness.

I sure would be nice to know whether my optimization can be solved in polynomial time.  Put another way, it sure would be embarrassing if a reviewer came back with five lines of pseudocode that finds the global maximum in O(n)..

Answer (score 0):

*Would, Query: abc Target: ..c.b.a.a Result: cba, be three permutations (as per your use of the term) then? If so, then maybe you mean transpositions rather than permutations. A transposition is the swapping of two adjacent characters.*

Good question.  We're interested in a mapping from Query -> Target that has as few *crossings*  as possible.  This is very much the motivation for mentioning the bipartite edge crossings in the original post.  Alternatively, you can think of maximizing a rank statistic, like Spearman's Rho, over the mapping.

*Also, out of curiousity, how many unique characters are there in the query/target? – Justin Peel 18*

Typical query: 100, typical target: 1000.  Combinatorially, it's a huge solution space.